# Creating row numbers based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I have the following dataset as input in my jupyter notebook:

```
Product   Year    Variable
A         2018        2
A         2019        4
B         2018        2
B         2019        3
```

I'm wondering what would be the quickest way to create a loop or something or that sorts in my data set, such that I get the following output:

```
Product   Year    Variable   Row_Num
A         2018        2         1
A         2018        2         2 
A         2019        4         1
A         2019        4         2
A         2019        4         3
A         2019        4         4
B         2018        2         1
B         2018        2         2
and so on...
```

TL;DR - Based on a variable in a particular column, I would like to create rows. Ex- if the variable is 3, I would like to create 3 copies of that row with a column that has values 1,2,3 against it.

One of the ways I think I found is to first create duplicates based on my variable and then use a function similar to rank() or row_number() to create my "row_num" column. It would be helpful if anyone can share other possible ways to do the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include both the input and the expected output **as text** in your question, so that others can easily reproduce it.

Comment: @Roy2012 Thank you Roy, I have updated the same. Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to create `n` duplicates of each row, where the value of `n` is given in one of the columns. Here's a way to do that:

```
df["new_id"] = df.Variable.apply(lambda x: list(range(x)))
df = df.explode("new_id")
```

Output:

```
  Product  Year  Variable new_id
0       A  2018         2      0
0       A  2018         2      1
1       A  2019         4      0
1       A  2019         4      1
1       A  2019         4      2
1       A  2019         4      3
2       B  2018         2      0
2       B  2018         2      1
3       B  2019         3      0
3       B  2019         3      1
3       B  2019         3      2
```

### Solution for Pandas <= 0.24

If for whatever reason, `explode` is not available because you're using an older version of pandas, you can do the following:

```
cols = df.columns

def make_df(r):
    d = {k: r[k] for k in cols}
    d["new_var"] = range(r["Variable"])
    res = pd.DataFrame(d)
    return res

dfs = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    dfs.append(make_df(row[1]))
    
pd.concat(dfs)
```

The output is identical.

Comment: Hi Roy, Thanks for this quick explanation, it is very clear and easy to understand. The first line of your answer has no issues for me.However, when I used the explode function like you mentioned, I got an error: **'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode**

Comment: Emm. What version of pandas are you using? Perhaps you need to update it?

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right. I'm working with Python 2.7.5. It must be importing an older version of pandas and thus causing this error. Thanks for your help Roy!
PS is there an alternative to explode by any chance?

Comment: Emm. Need to look into it.

Comment: Try upgrading to pandas 0.25. It works with python 2.7, and supports ‘explode’.